# Compiling in gcc dynamically with objects in other folders

Tags: c, gcc, include, dynamic-programming

I am developing a project with an ordeneted use of folders. I want a folder called /bin to store all the binary files and a folder called /src with all the .c and .h files.

The program will solve system of equations and all the functions related to matrix calculations will be compiled dynamically.

I have this folders:

/project/src/matrixlib  (it will be the fynamic lybrary with all the matrix calculations)

With files:

matrix.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"matrix.h"


int matrix_alloc(int n, int m, Matrix *matrix);
{
//do whatever, this is not the problem
}
```

matrix.h

```
#ifndef matrix_h__
#define matrix_h__

struct Matrix
{
//definition here
};typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

extern int matrix_alloc(int, int, Matrix*);
#endif //matrix_h__
```

I compile this folder with:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic matrix.c

gcc -shared -o libmatrix.so matrix.o
```

Then I have the folder:

/project/src/main

With files:

main.c (using function "matrix_alloc" and including "matrix.h")

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "matrix.h"

int main(void)
{
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix_alloc(3,3,&matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile like this:

```
gcc -I/project/src/matrixlib -L/project/src/matrixlib -Wl,-rpath=/project/src/matrixlib -Wall main.c -o  main
```

But I've got this error:

```
/tmp/cc8kLMIe.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `matrix_alloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I don't really understand what is going on because matrix_alloc is in matrix.h folder.

Could you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you miss some `-lmatrix` after `gcc ... main.c ... `?

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking `libmatrix.so` with your program. Add `-lmatrix` to your compiler invocation